# Notation of independence of random variables

Tags: probability, independence, notation

Consider $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ (random variables) with $X_1\sim \mu_1$, $X_2\sim \mu_2$, $X_1\sim \mu_3$ and some function $f$
$$
f = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathcal{Y}\\ 
X \mapsto \text{ some operations on } X_1, X_2 \text{ and } X_3
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Quite often, I see this kind of notation for independence of random variables:
$\mu =  \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3 $

Does it mean that $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ are mutually independent?

Comment: Could you point to a reference using it?

Comment: For instance, I see this notation in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-23395-6, p. 22.

Comment: The [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) is more usually employed for the $\sigma$-algebras and the regular 'x' product on the measures themselve.